# How to connect cpanel remote database with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpanel, mysql-python

I am trying to access cpanel database and records remotely. I used the following codes for sql connection, I have added "**%**" in the cpanel "**remote MySql**" to allow any ipaddress to access database remotely. but still i'am getting this error

```
import pymysql

    # Open database connection
    db = pymysql.connect("serverIpAddress","User","Password","DatabaseName")

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL query using execute() method.
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

    # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    print ("Database version : %s " % data)

    # disconnect from server
    db.close()
```

I am getting this error:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '184.164.144.130' (timed out)")
```

Comment: This is a network error, not a programming one. You most likely have the wrong IP address you're connecting to.

Comment: I have used cpanel Ip address as server Ip address as host Ip address. What Should be **ip address** of phpMyadmin ip address?